# Visual Studio 2012 can't see path to the libs etc after updating

Tags: visual-studio-2012, path, settings, static-libraries, include-path

I have installed VS 2012 which worked perfectly until last updating. Now it can't see common paths. I tryed to customize them but failed. For example I have some project being ok before but now there are glitches all around it:
[image]

here are current settings I done:
[image]

This is like those folders look:

[image]
[image]
[image]

While a new project is creating I get such messges:
[image]

Besides I have not found how to make settings global (not for only the single project). For sure all that is not very sophisticated but I have too little experience with VS. So I will very appreciate for real help!

And the current version is:

Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2012
Version 11.0.61030.00 Update 4
Microsoft .NET Framework
Version 4.5.50709

Installed Version: Professional

Team Explorer for Visual Studio 2012 04938-004-0033001-02302
Microsoft Team Explorer for Visual Studio 2012

Visual Basic 2012 04938-004-0033001-02302
Microsoft Visual Basic 2012

Visual C# 2012 04938-004-0033001-02302
Microsoft Visual C# 2012

Visual C++ 2012 04938-004-0033001-02302
Microsoft Visual C++ 2012

Visual F# 2012 04938-004-0033001-02302
Microsoft Visual F# 2012

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is resolved.
The cause was that before updating VS placed here:
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0
but after updating here:
B:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0
files which paths became broken left at the old location, i.e. here:
c:\Program Files (x86)\VC\
I really don't know why it is possible but reality is such just this.
So the solution was purely empirical:
1. Try to find lost files on the disk where VS was installed before:

[image]

2. Copy them into the directory where it is installed now:

[image]

3. Open any of projects to check if all is correct now:

[image]

Checked!